# change multiple occurences of a variable at once - aptana studio 3

Tags: eclipse, aptana

How can I change all occurences of one variable at once? in `sublime text` i can do this with `CTRL + D` , how can I do this in Aptana Studio 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the solution:

```
select variable -> right click -> refactoring -> rename
```